# How to use Graph QL inside HTML pages?

Tags: php, html, graphql, graphql-js

I want to perform graph QL calls from the html page and use all the advantages of the graph ql . I have tried several plugins and none of them seems to work perfrctly .Is there a way to do the graph ql with normal HRML page with some js library ?

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js
   https://graphql.org/graphql-js/

Answer (score 0):

Like AJAX calls, you need Javascript and GraphQL queries to be performed within Script Tag.
Use Prisma or Apollo servers to serve your queries as per the schemas.

Comment: Other than plain ajax calls is there any jquery plugins that can do graphql calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Fetch** with [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch)
This will work in modern browsers with no libraries but will require a polyfill in some browsers.

```js
require('isomorphic-fetch');

fetch('http://localhost:4000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ query: `
    query {
      todos {
        edges {
          node {
            completed
            id
            text
          }
    }
      }
    }` 
  }),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

In **Chrome’s DevTools** the following output will be printed to the console.
[image: output-graphql-api]